# Draft emails on Apple Mac

Tags: macbook-pro

Using Apple "Mail" I saved an email to "Drafts". I wanted to forward it to someone for review before sending it to the addressees. Having sent it I noticed that it is no longer in "Drafts". Can anyone tell me where it is & how to send it when I get the confirmation that it is ok?

Comment: It's only in drafts until you send it - then it moves to sent

Answer (score 1):

Emails saved as a draft only stay in Drafts until sent or deleted.  Once sent, a copy can be found in the Sent Mailbox.

To send again, select the target email in the Sent Mailbox and then press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or click: Message > Send Again

This opens the previously sent email in a new message container, where you can modify as needed/wanted and send again.

---

**Update:** Composed emails not sent are saved as drafts in the Drafts Mailbox. It is the normal and expected behavior when opening a draft email and sending it that it no longer be in the Drafts Mailbox and to think otherwise is illogical. It was after all sent!

In the future, if you have a draft email that you'd like to send, yet retain a copy in the Drafts Mailbox, e.g. send to a recipient for review before sending to other recipients, then you must first select the target email in the Drafts Mailbox and make a copy of it pressing ⌘C ⌘V and then double-click to open the saved draft.

You can then send what is the draft and still have an unsent copy of the draft to process further, as needed/wanted remaining in the Drafts Mailbox, because after all... it is a separate email container/object that has yet to be sent.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem. The draft is now part of the email sent to the 3rd party for review in the Sent Mailbox. It is no longer a separate email that can be sent to the 25 suggested addressees. I can copy & paste the text & add the addresses to a new email, but I am just being lazy & thought it should remain in Drafts since it had not been sent to the full distribution.

Comment: @David Bromilow, When I perform the suggested steps, what was a draft and now in the Sent mailbox and select it, then press ⇧⌘D, I now have exactly what was saved as a draft previously. I can change the To:, Cc: and or Bcc: fields removing the recipient(s) I sent it to and add additional recipients. I can leave the contents the same and or modify it and then send it to different recipients. What is sent is exactly the contents I want and no trace that it had been a draft previously sent. So I'm not sure what issue you're having expressed in your comment to my posted answer. See updated answer.